# rotate object list (with different origins) around a single pivot Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

i'm learning about Animation Nodes and i dont know a lot of things haha

I want to rotate some objects around a pivot point But i don't know how to do That!

Hmmm all is this: i've put a random text on the vertex points of a circle, so 've separated the text and started a loop with the circle as mesh input, i adjunct a picture with the nodes (if it can be made easier please tell me haha)...

[image]

The thing is: i can make those elements rotate on its own pivots but i cant make it with a vert on the mesh...

Ok, writting this question i've found the answer e.e (just rotate the circle that i've used as mesh) BUUUUUT now i'm curious, how can i rotate a object list around a 3rd pivot???

Thanks youu!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the render, so it's a little bit confusing to see what you want to achieve and ask, especially you change the question as well at the end. So **if I understand incorrectly your question, please point that out**.

I think maybe your are looking for the node called "**matrix math**".
A matrix is like an object, it contains "translation (similar to transform)", "rotation", "scale".
Matrix math currently only contains "multiply operator". The name may sound very confusing, but it allows to transform each individual matrix (ie. object).
[image]
[image]
Two images are used to states the **difference between *matrix math* and *transform matrix***.
matrix math works on object's own pivot. Transform matrix works on "world origin".

There are many operator that's only available to a matrix but not a vector. Such as "replicate matrix". So sometimes it may be preferred to "**compose a matrix**" for distributing objects, or simply use "**distribute matrix**" node for doing so.

Back to the most beginning, instead of using circles' vertex, you may simply use "distribute matrix", if you really are just looking for a circle.